# CSRF Token Mismatch Laravel 5..8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5.8

I"m having an issue that I don't know why it's showing this error. I have a form that's getting posted via ajax. I've added the hidden field meta tag in the head of my view. When I execute my ajax call I'm using Ajaxsetup to bring in the token.

Here's the html meta tag in the head of my view.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And my ajax call is

```
$('#login_model_submit').on('click', function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    let url = window.location.origin + '/login';
    let data = {
        'email': $('#login_email').val(),
        'password': $('#login_password').val(),
        '_token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function () {
            alert('Success')
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.responseText)
        }
    });
});
```

Don't know why I'm getting csrf token mismatch. I've done what I've seen in many of these question/answer on here and it's simple not working. Any help is great appreciated.

Here's my request headers

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 49
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: vb.local
Origin: http://vb.local
Referer: http://vb.local/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-TOKEN: YpP9izd705ztdtyqyFTBByLqcNmzoUIyb3i07HlA
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Have you used dev tools to verify that the header is actually being sent in the request?

Comment: Yes I have it's there but  still the error.

Comment: Try to change url e.g: `let url = '/login'`

Answer (score -1):

This problem comes from the CSRF token verification which fails. So either you're not posting one or you're posting an incorrect one.

Use `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your form

**OR**

Add Your Route URL into the `Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` file.

Example Like this. If your ajax route `Route::post('searchsubmit','User\UserController@ViewSearchList')->name('searchsubmit');`

**Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php**

```
protected $except = [
       'searchsubmit',
    ];
```

In Your Case You need to add `login` like this

```
protected $except = [
           'login',
        ];
```

Then Clear Cache by

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: @Eric Evans I m facing same issue and this solution works for me.